How to use environment variables in client side js script
I have a html file and a javascript code file.
The js file has a fetch call which requires i add a secret key, I have put this secret key in a .env file, how do i make this js script work when i add it to a script tag on the html file. below is the js code and how i want to add it to the script tag on the html file.
document.getElementById('getstarted').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const applicanturl = 'https://api.sumsub.com/resources/applicants';
  const applicantoptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-App-Token': process.env.Token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      externalUserId: '1234EERF', //Unique applicant identifier as registered on your side.
      email: 'vitaimiosior@gmail.com'
    })
  };

fetch(applicanturl, applicantoptions)
  .then(res => {
    res.json()
  })
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json)
  })
  .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));
})

here is what i want to do on the html file
<script src="../../applicant.js"></script>

This is what i have in my webpack.config.js file
const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/applicant.js',  // or wherever your entry file is
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"), // add this line
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
  mode: 'development', // or 'production'
};


I tried using webpack and browserify, they didn't work for me, maybe I am doing something wrong

You should configure this at run/deploy time (more: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html) but not you can not keep the token secret when it's used like this.

The script runs at the client side, which means that the secret needs to be known by the client, which means the end user is able to see/intercept/misuse the secret. Generally, you make a call from your client side to your server, and then the server makes a request to the API using that secret and then returns the response.

I think I should just keep everything on the server side

You should be making a request to your own backend where you can then make the API request. This ensures nothing will be exposed on the client! You can set up an ExpressJS server to handle requests like this

Some bundlers such as Vite support environment variables out of the box, and when the code is bundled, the variables are inserted directly, replacing process.env.[variable name]. You won't have access to a process variable by default on the client, you'll need to define it yourself.
It's always a bad idea to send environment variables to the client unless they're not sensitive and ok for public access. As Ivar said, a more secure approach would be making a server-side middleman for making requests with private tokens.
